# Are IRS audits triggered and conducted for a specific year or a range of tax years?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, audit

Let's assume that I have filed my taxes for 2017, 2018, and 2019. If my 2018 tax return triggers an audit, will I be required to provide information regarding my 2017 or 2019 taxes / finances (assuming my 2017 taxes are still within the statute of limitation of three years), or will there have to be separate triggers and audits for each individual tax year for that to happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The IRS has three years after filing but there are numerous exceptions.  It's six years if your return includes a substantial understatement of income, overstatement of basis, omission of significant foreign income.  There is no time limit if you never file a return or if the IRS can prove fraud. There are even circumstances where your tax returns indefinitely remain open for audit.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the information you provide in an audit for year X can trigger an audit for other years.

For example in Year X you didn't claim income from a side job because they paid you in cash, and you were a contractor. The company did submit a 1099 so they could claim the expense. It is possible that when the IRS was conducting the audit they determined that you had made less than $600 the previous year. The company didn't have to file a 1099 but you still had the claim the income. That could mean that the IRS wants to expand the audit to see if you had other unreported income in other years.

Comment: FWIW if you get selected for NRP, -- which is only a small fraction of exams, and exams of individuals are already well below 1% -- I'm pretty sure they can't expand beyond the year designated for statistical sampling. Against that, exam can't 'survey' you (drop you from exam because your return looks correct) and must cover nearly all lines, not just those that look 'large, unusual or questionable'.